# Регулярное выражение по замене свойства CSS в тексте

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

*В регулярных выражениях я пока новичок.*

Есть у меня текст, в нём куча спанов в стилях, у которых прописаны разный `font-size`. Надо все их привести к одному. Собираюсь использовать что-то вроде `str_replace()`, как-то так: `str_replace("/font-size: [любая цифра]px;/","font-size: 28px;,$sting")`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое выражение туда поставить, и правильно ли я подошёл к вопросу — может, там и не `str_replace()` нужно!

Comment: я могу вам книжку подарить по регуляркам 2015 года , на ozone 2000R стоит

Comment: Не str_replace, а preg_replace. И если работа разовая текст можно на regex101.com обработать. там и отладите свою регулярку (нужная вам регулярка пишется после 10 минут чтения статьи в википедии)

Comment: @LenovoID, книга в электронном виде?

Comment: ну конечно в электронном виде =>https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4AoB/1eebx7aSM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для замены по регулярному выражению, необходимо использовать функцию `preg_replace`. Число в регулярке можно записать различными способами, но если не извращаться, то самые популярные из них (то есть правильные) выглядят так: `\d+` или `[0-9]+`. В первом случае Вы используете уже имеющийся в ядре символьный класс, во втором - создаете свой. `+` говорит о том, что символ из символьного класса должен встретиться как минимум 1 раз, то есть схватывается первая цифра. Далее жадный алгоритм сразу съедает все цифры, следующие за первой, таким образом регулярка схватывает полностью всё число.

Ваш код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
preg_replace('/font-size: \d+px;/', 'font-size: 28px;', $sting);
```